# LaTeX beamer: get a picture in the foreground

Tags: beamer, tikz-pgf

I am trying to write some style file for a poster framework, we can use. The header is almost ready:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=15cm]{headline}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    %title text
    \node [anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,text width=60cm] at ($(current page.north west)+(4.5cm,-2.8cm)$)
        {
        {\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor{headline}\color{fg}\inserttitle\par}%
        \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
        \else%
            \vskip28mm\par%
            {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor{headline}\color{fg}\insertsubtitle\par}%
        \fi%
        %{\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor{headline}\color{fg}\insertauthor\par}%
        %   {\usebeamerfont{institute}\usebeamercolor{headline}\color{fg}\insertinstitute\par}              
        };
    %hzdr logo
    \node [anchor=north east,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north east)-(2cm,2.8cm)$)
        {\includegraphics[width=22.39cm,hiresbb]{HIF_E_weiss_auf_transparent}};
    %
    \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north east)-(-3cm,13cm)$)
        {\includegraphics[hiresbb]{PIKTO_ENGL_300DPI21}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

The last picture is out of the actual header. And it should be visible, i.e. should stay in the forerground, not matter what to add under the header of the poster.
Mainly the poster is made of other beamercolorboxes:

```
\newcommand\posterblock[4][]
{
    \fcolorbox{hzdr-blue}{white}{
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=1ex,#1]{bgblock}%use bigger values for colsep* if you want to make the box around the text bigger;warning: if you use the option rounded this will disable the horizontal spaces around the text
            \begin{block}{\usebeamerfont{block title}#2}\justify
                {\usebeamerfont{small block title}\color{hzdr-blue}{#3}}\vspace{2ex}

                {\usebeamerfont{block body}#4}
            \end{block}
        \end{beamercolorbox}}
        \quad
}
```

But when I am using this posterblock, it will always over the picture. Can anybody help and make the picture stay in the foreground?

Comment: Would you mind to include a minimal working (or not) example showing us what do you do? Which class do you use for your poster? When do you try to insert the foregraound picture? ...

Answer (score 1):

To make a picture stay in the background (all throughout) use the command

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{your_picture_file}}
```

You can adjust the `width` and `height` parameters to suit your need.

Comment: I am sorry, but using \usebackgroundtemplate instead of only \includegraphics results in no shown picture at all.